# Evaluate $\int_{0}^\infty x^ne^{−ax} dx$ where $a > 0$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: calculus

We consider the integral 
$\int_{0}^\infty x^ne^{−ax} dx$ where $a > 0$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$

(a) Evaluate the integral above if $n = 0$.

(b) Show that $\int_{0}^\infty x^n e^{−ax} dx = \frac{n}{a}\int_{0}^\infty x^{n-1}e^{−ax}$ for $n\geq 1$.

(c) And also, $\int_{0}^\infty x^ne^{−ax} dx = \frac{n(n-1)}{a^2}\int_{0}^\infty x^{n-2}e^{−ax}$

(d) Proof (by mathematical induction) that 
$\int_{0}^\infty x^ne^{−ax} dx = \frac{n!}{a^{n+1}}$
for $n\geq 1$.

Comment: Hello! What are your thoughts on this? Where are you stuck? On this community, we try to help other users, we don't answer questions for them. Hope that helps! Please edit your question with more information.

Comment: It would be better if you at least TRIED to do something by your own, instead of putting here your homework hoping for us to solve them.

Answer (score 1):

- (a) $n=0$ and $a>0$

$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-ax}dx=-\frac 1ae^{-ax}\Big{|}_{0}^{+\infty}=\frac 1a$$

- (b) $n\ge1$. Set $u=x^n$ and $e^{-ax}dx=dv$, we have
  $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}x^{n}e^{-ax}dx=\underbrace{-\frac{1}{a}x^{n}e^{-ax}\Big{|}_{0}^{+\infty}}_{0}+\frac{n}{a}\int_{0}^{+\infty}x^{n-1}e^{-ax}dx$$
- (c) Set Set $u=x^{n-1}$ and $e^{-ax}dx=dv$, we have

$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}x^{n}e^{-ax}dx=\frac{n}{a}\int_{0}^{+\infty}x^{n-1}e^{-ax}dx=\underbrace{-\frac{n}{a^2}x^{n-1}e^{-ax}\Big{|}_{0}^{+\infty}}_{0}+\frac{n(n-1)}{a^2}\int_{0}^{+\infty}x^{n-2}e^{-ax}dx$$

- (d) For $n=k$,  let
  $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}x^{k}e^{-ax}dx=\frac{k!}{a^{k+1}}$$
  we have
  $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}x^{k+1}e^{-ax}dx=\underbrace{\frac{k+1}{a}\int_{0}^{+\infty}x^{k}e^{-ax}dx}_{(b)}=\frac{k+1}{a}\times\frac{k!}{a^{k+1}}=\frac{(k+1)!}{a^{k+2}}$$
  Generally,if $\alpha,\beta$ and $a$ be posetive numbers, then 
  $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}x^{\alpha}e^{-ax^{\beta}}dx=\frac{1}{\beta\,a^{\frac{\alpha+1}{\beta}}}\Gamma\left(\frac{\alpha+1}{\beta}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

What is your question exactly?
a) = Simple integration of the exponential function
b) = Integration by parts
c) + d) = same as b) repeated